# Prove, for any nonnegative integer k, $[T^k]_\beta=([T]_\beta)^k$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\beta$ be an ordered basis for a finite-dimensional vector space V, and let $T:V \rightarrow V$ be linear. Prove, for any nonnegative integer k, $[T^k]_\beta=([T]_\beta)^k$

So the general approach is by induction, and then by linearity we can arrive at the equality right?

Comment: Your idea should work

Comment: Azif00 gave an answer below, which shows, what the main part of the proof is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's right, it can be done by induction. But, the main idea behind this is when you have two linear maps, $T$ and $U$, then $[TU]_\beta = [T]_\beta [U]_\beta$.